# При работе jar не открывается консоль

Tags: jar

Собрал .jar c помощью maven.
Клацаю на джарник - всё работает: файлы переименовывает, как и задумано.
Программа по окончанию должна показать отчет, но консоль не открывалась.
Если запускать через "java -jar renamer.jar" - то да: всё видно.

Как сделать что бы при открытии .jar консоль открывалась автоматически?

Comment: Прикрутите логгер к проекту и выводите в файл, например. Консоль - это частный случай "окружения", в котором запускается проект. Если именно в консоль хотите, наверное нужен батник на запуск в консоли приложения с перенаправлением вывода

Comment: Ну это не совсем тот вариант. Программа будет спрашивать пользователя какое расширение файла должно быть. По этому по-любому нужна консоль.

Comment: Посмотрите в сторону класса java.io.Console

Comment: Посмотрел. Это утилитный класс для работы с консолью. Там нет способа для её самостоятельного открытия во время работы программы.

Comment: Если в ладах с английским, почитайте http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7704405/how-do-i-make-my-java-application-open-a-console-terminal-window

Comment: Спасибо огромнейшое!

Answer (score 1):

По ссылке в коментах есть инструкция:

```
 public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception{
        Console console = System.console();
        if (console == null && !GraphicsEnvironment.isHeadless()) {
            String filename = Main.class.getProtectionDomain().getCodeSource().getLocation().toString().substring(6);
            Runtime.getRuntime().exec(new String[]{"cmd", "/c", "start", "cmd", "/k", "java -jar \"" + filename + "\""});
        }
        else {
            ClassThatNeedToStartWithCommandPromt.main(new String[0]);
        }
    }
}
```

Это работает!